# HTTP Status 404 - /first/ error

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat

When I run the project, I'm getting

> HTTP Status 404 - `/first/`
>   type Status report
>   message `/first/`
>   description The requested resource is not available.
>   Apache Tomcat/8.0.32

My web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>first</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>login</display-name>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>login</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>index</display-name>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>login1</display-name>
    <servlet-name>login1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>login1</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login1</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>login2</display-name>
    <servlet-name>login2</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>login2</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>login2</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login2</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My servlet file:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
public class login2 extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        //request.getRequestDispatcher("link.html").include(request, response);
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        if (password.equals("wadha")) {
            out.print("Welcome, " + name);
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("name", name);
        } else {
            out.print("Sorry, username or password error!");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html").include(request, response);
        }
        out.close();
    }
}
```

My JSP file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="login.html">Login</a>|  
<form action="login" method="post">  
Name:<input type="text" name="name"><br>  
Password:<input type="password" name="password"><br>  
<input type="submit" value="login">  
</form>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: shouldn't the `servlet-class` be defined with full-name (package name+ class name) ? i think you are having exceptions while deploying that webapp (check tomcat logs), and thus you are getting that 404 ?

Comment: thank you for your help but, still l'm getting same error

Comment: i follow some solutions that are in the google but nothing happen.